# Cannot implicitly convert <type> to the LFFolder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, oop, scripting

So I'm writing a C# test script for a Laserfiche server, and my code goes like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    conn.Create(db);
    LFFolder testdir = db.GetEntryByPath(testdirloc);
    LFDocument test;
    test.Create("test", testdir, vol, true);
    test.Dispose();
    conn.Terminate();
}
```

When I build it, I get told:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'LFSO82Lib.LFFolder'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is terrible news. According to the Laserfiche Integrator's Kit, LFSO82Lib.LFFolder is a LFFolder object, and the method GetEntryByPath("Path") gets you a LFFolder object. I know this is true because when I write the code equivalent for this in VB.NET, it works.

For those unfamiliar with Laserfiche servers, LFFolder is simply an object in LFSO82Lib, apparently obtainable by various GetEntryBy_*_*_ methods, but evidently not. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using explicit conversion:

```
LFFolder testdir = (LFFolder)db.GetEntryByPath(testdirloc);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why does the way I did it not work? I've been able to initiate other variables fine, like: LFServer serv = app.GetServerByName("LF-Name"); Is there something crucial I'm missing that forces explicit conversion?

Comment: @Tim: I'm sorry, I don't use those objects and I don't know the reason. Anyway the error was so explcit that solution came easy in my mind. I'm glad this solved your trouble :)

Comment: @Tim: in VS put your mouse on `GetEntryByPath` and wait for syntax to appear or press F12 to go to definition; check what kind of object is returned: is it an `object` or a `LFFolder`?

Answer (score 0):

You weren't casting your returned object as mentioned above.  The laserfiche GetEntryByPath() method returns an ILFEntry object which could be either an LFFolder or LFDocument object, therefore you must cast the object to which type you want before loading it into a new variable.  This is pretty common in LFSO with C#.